# Open a Dialog From Inside Keyboard Android

Tags: java, android, mobile, dialog, keyboard

So I have this Keyboard App I'm making.

I get the words the user type in, and after he/she types some specific word, I want to display a dialog message, with yes/no answer.

I can make the app show a Toast and it works, but then i may have no feedback from the user.

If I use this code:

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(palavra.length(), 0);
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                dialog.dismiss();
                break;
        }
    }
};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

I get an error because I have no activity to use in 'context'. I just have the KeyboardView.

How can I manage to make this right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `KeyboardView` is a subclass of `View`, you should be able to call `getContext()`. For example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

I made it!

This is my code now (and it works perfectly!):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Palavra  ofensiva")
        .setMessage("Deseja mudar a palavra?")
        .create();

alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Sim",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        ic.deleteSurroundingText(palavra.length(), 0);
        palavra = "";
    }
});
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
alertDialog.show();
```